# Auto-populate GL account based on WO classification

Tags: configuration, maximo, accounting, auto-populate

I have work order classifications in Maximo 7.6.1.1:

[image]

---

I plan to add a field called `GL Account` to the classifications:

[image]

---

When I create a work order, I would like to automatically populate the WO's `GL Account` value via the selected WO classification.

**What would it take to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to populate your classification GL account with a custom crossover domain that you'd set on the WORKORDER.CLASSSTRUCTUREID field. Your custom GL field would be bound to WORKORDER.GLACCOUNT.

Look at the WORKORDER CLASSSTRUCTURE relationship to get the where clause that you'd need to set on your new domain's validation and list where clauses. This should look like this:`classstructureid = :classstructureid`

Check the other crossover domains associated to the WORKORDER objects such as ASSET2WO, LOC2WO, etc. to get an idea on how it works.

Also, have a look at this IBM documentation for more info on crossover domains:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.0/com.ibm.mt.doc/domainadm/t_add_crossover_domain.html

Comment: This really saved my butt. My consultant claimed that it wasn't possible. But I knew there had to be a way. Thanks again.